# How to close Kyle Fox Modal dialog with JQuery

Tags: jquery, dialog

I want to show part of my page in a modal fashion.

I'm planning on using [Kyle Fox's Modal](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal) jQuery for this.

His code samples give a closing link for the dialog like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a> or press ESC</p>
```

I'm sure this will work, but how could I invoke modal close, without having to have the link somewhere.

Comment: `how could I invoke modal close, without having to have the link somewhere` means you don't want to show the close link??

Comment: that's right there is some ajax com going on while the dialog is active, part of the processing of the result is closing the dialog when conditions are met.

Comment: I tried to add a new tag to indicate this specific plugging. Since it's a plugging with specific characteristics and documentation. But I don't have enough rep (1500 needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you initialize the modal class. But in general its:

```
$.modal.close();
```

this closes all existing modal.

lets you want to close the modal on click into some div element you might want to add a new event-listener which triggers the close like this:

In your html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

in your JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#container', $.modal.close);
```